# Find if PowerShell argument is an empty string and prompt for input

Tags: powershell

I have a nice PowerShell function that I want to prompt "please enter a value" if I get an empty string and not process if the trimmed argument is empty.

```
function Find-Process([String] $AppName){

    netstat -ano | Select-String $AppName
}
```

Comment: you may need to do `$PID = (Get-Process $AppName).Id` and `Select-String $PID` since -ano doesn't give exe names, you'd need to use -anb to get the process names instead, and use `Select-String $AppName -Context 0,1` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For parameters, you can use [`ValidateNotNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1#ValidateNotNullOrEmpty):

```
function Find-Process{
    param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String] $AppName
    )
    Write-Host $Appname
}
```

Error message when a null or empty argument is provided:

> Find-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'AppName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
>   argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

---

You may want to consider `[parameter(Mandatory=$true)]` if you do not want the function to run without that argument.

Answer (score 4):

If User does not provide any value to AppName Parameter, it will prompt the user for a value. You can also make the AppName parameter as Mandatory.

```
function Find-Process([String] $AppName){

    If ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($AppName)) { $AppName = Read-Host 'Please enter a value' }    

    If ($AppName) { netstat -ano | Select-String $AppName 
    }
    Else { 
          'Value not provided'    
    }
}
```

#

```
function Find-Process{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $AppName
    )
     netstat -ano | Select-String $AppName
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters validation to check if the value is empty instead of propose a prompt if not.

With this code, the function cannot be called if `$AppName` is empty or null

```
function Find-Process{
    Param(
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()][String]$AppName
    )
    netstat -ano | Select-String $AppName
}
```