# Validate 2 Powershell Parameters

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function that moves files and folders from one directory to another. I want to be able to make sure neither value for `$fromFolder` or `$toFolder` is empty or null. Not sure how it would work with two parameters.

```
function Move-Folders {
    gci $fromFolder -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $toFolder }
    ii $toFolder
}
```

Comment: You create a function that does exactly the same as `Move-Item`. There's no need to browse with `gci` as you move everything without filtering so just use `Move-Item`, it will be more accurate. However I have provided an answer with how to validate your parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find if PowerShell argument is an empty string and prompt for input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47181052/find-if-powershell-argument-is-an-empty-string-and-prompt-for-input)

Answer (score 2):

Declare the parameters with validation attributes : [about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1)

```
function Move-Folders {
    Param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]
        $fromFolder,

        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [String]
        $toFolder
    )

    gci $fromFolder -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $toFolder }
    ii $toFolder
}
```

Comment: For reference: they're called attributes.  Also, as a code style point, I'd recommend putting each attribute above the `[Type]$Declaration` on its own line for readability.  In some scripts I've written, I've used `[ValidateScript()]` or have multiple attributes where your method quickly becomes unruly.

Comment: I agree with you, I did one-liner because of the `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()` that is simple. I edit to follow the good practice rules.

Answer (score 0):

This should do your work with mandatory parameters:

```
function Move-Folders {
Param(
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   $fromFolder,
   [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
   $toFolder

) #end param

gci $fromFolder -Recurse | ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $toFolder }

ii $toFolder
}
```